# how to use select_related in templates Django?

Tags: django

```
class FinalVideo(models.Model):
    source = models.ForeignKey(UploadedVideo)
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

```
class UploadedVideo(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

in urls.py:

```
'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', {'queryset': FinalVideo.objects.select_related()},
```

in template:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
```

How to get type in template for each object ?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean by "get type in template"? All your objects have type `FinalVideo`

Comment: This may be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523698/django-select-related-in-template

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to access field "type" of class UploadedVideo through object instance of FinalVideo?
Try this:
in urls.py:

`'django.views.generic.list_detail.object_list', {'queryset': FinalVideo.objects.select_related("source").all()},`

in template:

```
{% for object in object_list %}
    {% for uploaded_video in object.source_set.all %}
        {{ uploaded_video.type }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```